# Why isn't this replace of backslash working?

Tags: c#, regex, replace, filepath, backslash

So I need to remove escaped backslashes from a string (in my case, a path simply like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE\").

To replace I've tried the following:

```
String openWith = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\WINWORD.EXE";

string newString = openWith.Replace(@"\\", @"\");

openWith = openWith.Replace(@"\\", @"\");

openWith = Regex.Replace(openWith,"\\\\","\\");
```

But none of these work!! Would anyone be able to explain to me why this may be?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string doesn't contain doubled backslashes.

The first backslash in `"C:\\"` is an escape character which is interpreted by the C# compiler. At runtime however the string only contains single backslashes. You can prove this to yourself by displaying the value of the string:

```
String openWith = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\WINWORD.EXE";
Console.WriteLine(openWith);
```

Result:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE
```

Note that there are only single backslashes in the output.

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/jjJEV)

Comment: I am creating file in the path but it gives me IOException. And the reason is that file path contains double slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove back slash from the path you put in the question.

The path with double backslash `\\` is the only possible *visualization* of a **valid** IO path on Windows OS.